# HardFaultHandler in STM32

Tags: bluetooth-lowenergy, stm32, stm32cubemx

I am using a NUCLEO-WB15CC board trying to build a BLE application.

I followed the instruction from a YT video by STM: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=i10X4Blr8ns

I generated code with CubeMX version6-5-0 on linux.

The code called HardFaultHandler() as soon as it reach MX_APPE_Init() in main.c

if i break the while(1) loop in HardFaultHandler, the code continues at __HAL_RTC_WAKEUPTIMER_DISABLE(phrtc) in HW_TS_RTC_Wakeup_Handler() from Core/Src/hw_timerserver.c.

Why is that so? How do I rectify or solve this?

Thanks!

Below is main.c

```
#include "main.h"

 IPCC_HandleTypeDef hipcc;

RTC_HandleTypeDef hrtc;

UART_HandleTypeDef huart1;
DMA_HandleTypeDef hdma_usart1_rx;
DMA_HandleTypeDef hdma_usart1_tx;


void SystemClock_Config(void);
void PeriphCommonClock_Config(void);
static void MX_GPIO_Init(void);
static void MX_IPCC_Init(void);
static void MX_RF_Init(void);
static void MX_DMA_Init(void);
static void MX_RTC_Init(void);

int main(void)
{
  /* MCU Configuration--------------------------------------------------------*/

  /* Reset of all peripherals, Initializes the Flash interface and the Systick. */
  HAL_Init();
  /* Config code for STM32_WPAN (HSE Tuning must be done before system clock configuration) */
  MX_APPE_Config();

  /* Configure the system clock */
  SystemClock_Config();

/* Configure the peripherals common clocks */
  PeriphCommonClock_Config();

  /* IPCC initialisation */
   MX_IPCC_Init();

  /* Initialize all configured peripherals */
  MX_GPIO_Init();
  MX_RF_Init();
  MX_DMA_Init();
  MX_RTC_Init();

  /* Init code for STM32_WPAN */
  MX_APPE_Init();

  /* Infinite loop */
  /* USER CODE BEGIN WHILE */
  while (1)
  {

    /* USER CODE END WHILE */
    MX_APPE_Process();

    /* USER CODE BEGIN 3 */

  }
  /* USER CODE END 3 */
}

/**
  * @brief System Clock Configuration
  * @retval None
  */
void SystemClock_Config(void)
{
  RCC_OscInitTypeDef RCC_OscInitStruct = {0};
  RCC_ClkInitTypeDef RCC_ClkInitStruct = {0};

  /** Configure LSE Drive Capability
  */
  HAL_PWR_EnableBkUpAccess();
  __HAL_RCC_LSEDRIVE_CONFIG(RCC_LSEDRIVE_LOW);

  /** Initializes the RCC Oscillators according to the specified parameters
  * in the RCC_OscInitTypeDef structure.
  */
  RCC_OscInitStruct.OscillatorType = RCC_OSCILLATORTYPE_HSI|RCC_OSCILLATORTYPE_HSE
                              |RCC_OSCILLATORTYPE_LSE;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.HSEState = RCC_HSE_ON;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.LSEState = RCC_LSE_ON;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.HSIState = RCC_HSI_ON;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.HSICalibrationValue = RCC_HSICALIBRATION_DEFAULT;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL.PLLState = RCC_PLL_NONE;
  if (HAL_RCC_OscConfig(&RCC_OscInitStruct) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }

  /** Configure the SYSCLKSource, HCLK, PCLK1 and PCLK2 clocks dividers
  */
  RCC_ClkInitStruct.ClockType = RCC_CLOCKTYPE_HCLK4|RCC_CLOCKTYPE_HCLK2
                              |RCC_CLOCKTYPE_HCLK|RCC_CLOCKTYPE_SYSCLK
                              |RCC_CLOCKTYPE_PCLK1|RCC_CLOCKTYPE_PCLK2;
  RCC_ClkInitStruct.SYSCLKSource = RCC_SYSCLKSOURCE_HSE;
  RCC_ClkInitStruct.AHBCLKDivider = RCC_SYSCLK_DIV1;
  RCC_ClkInitStruct.APB1CLKDivider = RCC_HCLK_DIV1;
  RCC_ClkInitStruct.APB2CLKDivider = RCC_HCLK_DIV1;
  RCC_ClkInitStruct.AHBCLK2Divider = RCC_SYSCLK_DIV1;
  RCC_ClkInitStruct.AHBCLK4Divider = RCC_SYSCLK_DIV1;

  if (HAL_RCC_ClockConfig(&RCC_ClkInitStruct, FLASH_LATENCY_1) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
}

/**
  * @brief Peripherals Common Clock Configuration
  * @retval None
  */
void PeriphCommonClock_Config(void)
{
  RCC_PeriphCLKInitTypeDef PeriphClkInitStruct = {0};

  /** Initializes the peripherals clock
  */
  PeriphClkInitStruct.PeriphClockSelection = RCC_PERIPHCLK_SMPS|RCC_PERIPHCLK_RFWAKEUP;
  PeriphClkInitStruct.RFWakeUpClockSelection = RCC_RFWKPCLKSOURCE_LSE;
  PeriphClkInitStruct.SmpsClockSelection = RCC_SMPSCLKSOURCE_HSI;
  PeriphClkInitStruct.SmpsDivSelection = RCC_SMPSCLKDIV_RANGE1;

  if (HAL_RCCEx_PeriphCLKConfig(&PeriphClkInitStruct) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }

}

/**
  * @brief IPCC Initialization Function
  * @param None
  * @retval None
  */
static void MX_IPCC_Init(void)
{

  hipcc.Instance = IPCC;
  if (HAL_IPCC_Init(&hipcc) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }

}

/**
  * @brief RF Initialization Function
  * @param None
  * @retval None
  */
static void MX_RF_Init(void)
{


}

/**
  * @brief RTC Initialization Function
  * @param None
  * @retval None
  */
static void MX_RTC_Init(void)
{
  /** Initialize RTC Only
  */
  hrtc.Instance = RTC;
  hrtc.Init.HourFormat = RTC_HOURFORMAT_24;
  hrtc.Init.AsynchPrediv = CFG_RTC_ASYNCH_PRESCALER;
  hrtc.Init.SynchPrediv = CFG_RTC_SYNCH_PRESCALER;
  hrtc.Init.OutPut = RTC_OUTPUT_DISABLE;
  hrtc.Init.OutPutPolarity = RTC_OUTPUT_POLARITY_HIGH;
  hrtc.Init.OutPutRemap = RTC_OUTPUT_REMAP_NONE;
  if (HAL_RTC_Init(&hrtc) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }

  /** Enable the WakeUp
  */
  if (HAL_RTCEx_SetWakeUpTimer_IT(&hrtc, 0, RTC_WAKEUPCLOCK_RTCCLK_DIV16) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
}

/**
  * @brief USART1 Initialization Function
  * @param None
  * @retval None
  */
void MX_USART1_UART_Init(void)
{

  huart1.Instance = USART1;
  huart1.Init.BaudRate = 115200;
  huart1.Init.WordLength = UART_WORDLENGTH_8B;
  huart1.Init.StopBits = UART_STOPBITS_1;
  huart1.Init.Parity = UART_PARITY_NONE;
  huart1.Init.Mode = UART_MODE_TX_RX;
  huart1.Init.HwFlowCtl = UART_HWCONTROL_NONE;
  huart1.Init.OverSampling = UART_OVERSAMPLING_8;
  huart1.Init.OneBitSampling = UART_ONE_BIT_SAMPLE_DISABLE;
  huart1.Init.ClockPrescaler = UART_PRESCALER_DIV1;
  huart1.AdvancedInit.AdvFeatureInit = UART_ADVFEATURE_NO_INIT;
  if (HAL_UART_Init(&huart1) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
  if (HAL_UARTEx_SetTxFifoThreshold(&huart1, UART_TXFIFO_THRESHOLD_1_8) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
  if (HAL_UARTEx_SetRxFifoThreshold(&huart1, UART_RXFIFO_THRESHOLD_1_8) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
  if (HAL_UARTEx_DisableFifoMode(&huart1) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }

}

/**
  * Enable DMA controller clock
  */
static void MX_DMA_Init(void)
{

  /* DMA controller clock enable */
  __HAL_RCC_DMAMUX1_CLK_ENABLE();
  __HAL_RCC_DMA1_CLK_ENABLE();

  /* DMA interrupt init */
  /* DMA1_Channel1_IRQn interrupt configuration */
  HAL_NVIC_SetPriority(DMA1_Channel1_IRQn, 0, 0);
  HAL_NVIC_EnableIRQ(DMA1_Channel1_IRQn);
  /* DMA1_Channel2_IRQn interrupt configuration */
  HAL_NVIC_SetPriority(DMA1_Channel2_IRQn, 0, 0);
  HAL_NVIC_EnableIRQ(DMA1_Channel2_IRQn);

}

/**
  * @brief GPIO Initialization Function
  * @param None
  * @retval None
  */
static void MX_GPIO_Init(void)
{
  GPIO_InitTypeDef GPIO_InitStruct = {0};

  /* GPIO Ports Clock Enable */
  __HAL_RCC_GPIOC_CLK_ENABLE();
  __HAL_RCC_GPIOA_CLK_ENABLE();
  __HAL_RCC_GPIOB_CLK_ENABLE();
  __HAL_RCC_GPIOE_CLK_ENABLE();

  /*Configure GPIO pin Output Level */
  HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOB, LD2_Pin|LD3_Pin|LD1_Pin, GPIO_PIN_RESET);

  /*Configure GPIO pin : B1_Pin */
  GPIO_InitStruct.Pin = B1_Pin;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Mode = GPIO_MODE_INPUT;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Pull = GPIO_NOPULL;
  HAL_GPIO_Init(B1_GPIO_Port, &GPIO_InitStruct);

  /*Configure GPIO pin : B3_Pin */
  GPIO_InitStruct.Pin = B3_Pin;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Mode = GPIO_MODE_INPUT;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Pull = GPIO_PULLUP;
  HAL_GPIO_Init(B3_GPIO_Port, &GPIO_InitStruct);

  /*Configure GPIO pins : LD2_Pin LD3_Pin LD1_Pin */
  GPIO_InitStruct.Pin = LD2_Pin|LD3_Pin|LD1_Pin;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Mode = GPIO_MODE_OUTPUT_PP;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Pull = GPIO_NOPULL;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Speed = GPIO_SPEED_FREQ_LOW;
  HAL_GPIO_Init(GPIOB, &GPIO_InitStruct);

  /*Configure GPIO pin : B2_Pin */
  GPIO_InitStruct.Pin = B2_Pin;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Mode = GPIO_MODE_INPUT;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Pull = GPIO_PULLUP;
  HAL_GPIO_Init(B2_GPIO_Port, &GPIO_InitStruct);

}

/**
  * @brief  This function is executed in case of error occurrence.
  * @retval None
  */
void Error_Handler(void)
{
  /* USER CODE BEGIN Error_Handler_Debug */
  /* User can add his own implementation to report the HAL error return state */
  __disable_irq();
  while (1)
  {
  }
  /* USER CODE END Error_Handler_Debug */
}

#ifdef  USE_FULL_ASSERT
/**
  * @brief  Reports the name of the source file and the source line number
  *         where the assert_param error has occurred.
  * @param  file: pointer to the source file name
  * @param  line: assert_param error line source number
  * @retval None
  */
void assert_failed(uint8_t *file, uint32_t line)
{
  /* USER CODE BEGIN 6 */
  /* User can add his own implementation to report the file name and line number,
     ex: printf("Wrong parameters value: file %s on line %d\r\n", file, line) */
  /* USER CODE END 6 */
}
#endif /* USE_FULL_ASSERT */
```

Comment: you are asking the most difficult and challenging question in ARM core development. There are hundreds of possible problems, and it is not possible ti answer without having the board especially because you have not idea what the program is doing under the hood

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Hi, try replace in the while the next line -    
MX_APPE_Process() to UTIL_SEQ_Run( UTIL_SEQ_DEFAULT)